# Start my iPhone app on the end of call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-telephony

I want to develop an app which records the call-duration etc.. when a call is finished. So is it possible to start my app when the user finishes his call.

App is currently not running and then

```
User Finishes his Call ---> My app should open up the moment he finishes his call giving me the details about call duration etc.. and then i ask for some comments on that page and exit the app.
```

I already made such an app in Android,Blackberry.

P.S: Even if it works on a jailbroken iPhone it is good enough for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this on a regular iPhone. Apple's APIs don't allow you to interfere with phone calls at all.

Not sure about jailbroken phones though. In theory, you can do anything, it just depends on how much time you're willing to spend on it. Good luck.

Comment: Hey,I am new to iPhone dev..So i found this CTCall object in CoreTelephony which gives me info about the current call status.. so when it becomes "disconnected" is it possible to launch my application based on this event? Thanks!